# How can I create a wordpress detail page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a Wordpress site page (5.7 version) called Ranking with all athletes showed (url = "https://example.com/ranking").
For every athletes showed I create a button link for display all athlete details.
What I would like is that by clicking button (for example athleteId=2352), the page to open will be = "https://example.com/athlete/2352.
How can I create athlete page?
Do I change only permalink?
Do I Have to rewrite my theme rules?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just create a template and redirect with id in query string. not required rewrite rules

Answer (score 0):

Look into creating a custom post type for the purpose. You should then have control of rewrite rules, archive slug etc.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

And as ed2 mentions, please be more clear in your questions. It makes it easier to help out, and more useful for others with the same issue as yourself

Comment: thanks for replying zencode. my question was to understand which procedure to take rather than a specific technical request with code. However I solved it by passing the id in query params

Comment: @pmala84 - That was exactly my point. If you registered it as a public custom post type, you could link directly to the athlete's permalink, instead of doing custom rewrites etc.